# Elegant way to assign object id in Java

Tags: java

I have a class for objects ... lat's say apples.

Each apple object mush have a unique identifier (id)... how do I ensure (elegantly and efficiently) that newly created has unique id.

Thanks

Comment: What does your `Apple` class look like?

Comment: How about using a UUID? http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Comment: you could create a global counter, and assign the id in the constructor. i'm not sure if this is the best idea though.

Comment: I am curious why you ended up using AtomicInteger. If you restart the app, then the application will reset the nextId to 0. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

have a `static int nextId` in your Apple class and increment it in your constructor.

It would probably be prudent to ensure that your incrementing code is atomic, so you can do something like this (using AtomicInteger). This will guarantee that if two objects are created at exactly the same time, they do not share the same Id.

```
public class Apple {
    static AtomicInteger nextId = new AtomicInteger();
    private int id;

    public Apple() {
        id = nextId.incrementAndGet();
   }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using synchronized, you could use an atomic type for the counter instead

Comment: Might be nicer to use [AtomicInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) for something like this.

Comment: this won't work. You'd better synchronize on `Apple.class` (or use `AtomicInteger` as others suggested)

Comment: just to be on the safe side, it would be wise to declare the static field also "private"

Comment: Updated as suggested. Decided against making it private, in case of extension and it needed to be altered.

Comment: Don't synchronize if you are using an AtomicInteger.

Comment: `nextId` should be private and `id` should be final.

Comment: It should be `private int id` instead of `private id`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 13):

Use `java.util.UUID.randomUUID()`

It is not `int`, but it is guaranteed to be unique:

> A class that represents an immutable universally unique identifier (UUID).

---

If your objects are somehow managed (for example by some persistence mechanism), it is often the case that the manager generates the IDs - taking the next id from the database, for example.

Related: [Jeff Atwood's article on GUIDs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html) (UUIDs). It is database-related, though, but it's not clear from your question whether you want your objects to be persisted or not.

Answer (score 5):

Have you thought about using [UUID](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class. You can call the randomUUID() function to create a new id everytime.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to get unique ID's. Instead of using an int or other data type, just make a class:

```
final class ID
{
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o)
  {
     return this==o;
  }
}

public Apple
{
  final private ID id=new ID();
}
```

Thread safe without synchronizing!

Comment: Nice, but not when one needs comparable ids.